# Разница между 2-мя датами

Tags: c#, datetime

Как я могу получить разницу между 2 датами
в формате MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss?

Например было 22/10/2018 15:00:00, потом 23/10/2018 17:35:00 - и как высчитать сколько прошло?(Например прошло 1 день 2часа 35 минут)

Comment: можно воспользоваться стандартным методом [Substract](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Взято с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

Для ленивых:

```
(EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays
```

В вашем случае:

```
(EndDate - StartDate).TotalHours / 24
```

Получите количество дней + часы в остатке

***UPD***:
Нашёл более адекватное решение. Пример:

```
var x = DateTime.Now;
var y = DateTime.Now.AddHours(10.5);
var z = (y - x).Duration();
Console.WriteLine($"{z.Days} {z.Hours} {z.Minutes}");
// outputs: 0 10 30
```

Comment: или как вариант [substract](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно спарсить дату и посчитать разность.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact("22/10/2018 15:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact("23/10/2018 17:35:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan result = end - start;
```